# ASP.NET MVC 3 - loop out data at View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I don't know how to loop out data from child class in view in asp.net mvc3.
Please see below.

I have following structure :

```
//Controller
Store.cs
Public Class Store()
{
    //Constructor
    ProductCat pCat = new ProductCat();
    Item item = new Item();         
}
Public Class StoreList : Base<Store>()
{ }

ProdctCat.cs
Public Class ProductCat()
{  }
Public Class ProductCatList : Base<ProductCat>()
{}

Item.cs
Publie Class Item()
{ }
Public Class ItemList : Base<Item>()
{ }


//And I pased the StoreList class to view as following
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<StoreList>" %>
<%                                                 
         for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
         {
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[i].StoreName)%>                  
         }
%>
```

I am using MVC 3 View User Control (ASPX), not any other view engine.
What I know is, we can loop out data like this : model[i].StoreName.
But I don't know how to loop out data from ProductCatList class of current Store.
Example :

```
for( int j = 0 ; j < model[i].ProductCatList ; j++)
{
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model[j].ProductCatName)%>                  
}
```

Could someone advice me how can do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is the link between `StoreList` and `ProductCatList`?

Comment: StoreList is just for saving data about of store name, store description, store location.And ProductCatList is for saving data about product category information like ProductCategory Name , ProductCategoryDescription.

Comment: For linking StoreList and ProductCat List,we added ProductCatList in constructor of Store class as I mentioned above.